# Why is method1 and method2 the same at the Bytecode level?

Tags: java, bytecode

I wrote this simple `Test` class to see how Java evaluates `boolean` algebra at the Bytecode level:

```
public class Test {

    private static boolean a, b;

    public static boolean method1(){
        return !(a || b);
    }

    public static boolean method2(){
        return !a && !b;
    }
}
```

If you simplify `method1()` using [DeMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), you should get `method2()`. After looking at the Bytecode (using javap -c Test.class), it looks like:

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
    public Test();
    Code:
            0: aload_0
    1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":
            ()V
    4: return

    public static boolean method1();
    Code:
            0: getstatic     #2                  // Field a:Z
            3: ifne          16
            6: getstatic     #3                  // Field b:Z
            9: ifne          16
            12: iconst_1
    13: goto          17
            16: iconst_0
    17: ireturn

    public static boolean method2();
    Code:
            0: getstatic     #2                  // Field a:Z
            3: ifne          16
            6: getstatic     #3                  // Field b:Z
            9: ifne          16
            12: iconst_1
    13: goto          17
            16: iconst_0
    17: ireturn
}
```

So my question is, why is `method1()` and `method2()` exactly the same at the Bytecode level?

Comment: Compiler optimizations!

Comment: This may be a dumb comment.. but the two methods produce the same result, though in a different way of writing it. Your question is why the bytecode is the same, isn't that obvious?

Comment: Uhhh, you answered this question yourself. The two expressions **are** the same, so the compiler optimized them the same. It's probably slightly faster to execute the `method2` version than the `method1` version so that's where the compiler aims.

Comment: @dcsohl But why does `method1` look like `method2` as opposed to `method2` looking like `method1`? Why do you think `method2` has a slightly faster execution time as opposed to `method1`?

Comment: What would the bytecode for `method1` look like in your expectation?

Comment: @abmitchell: I have yet to see a compiler that turns `{ List t = new List(); for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) { t.add(i); } int r = 0; for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) { r += t[i]; } return r; }` into simply `{ return 499500; }`.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call this a compiler "optimization," in that this is just the way the compiler compiles boolean expressions -- and the branching involved in conditional ANDs and ORS -- to Java bytecode generally.

Comment: @Josh I would imagine it has to do with short circuiting. `a` and `b` are (by default) false, so `method2` only has to do one comparison. NB this is just a guess.

Comment: @Joker_vD That snippet relies on the `List` class, which may not be the same in different runtime environments.  Of course a compiler wouldn't optimize that away.  However, if you used pure Java constructs and not classes (such as `int[1000]`), compilers can unroll and optimize away loops at higher optimization levels.

Comment: Shouldn't be constant propagation used here? Given that `a` and `b` are false by default, thus the result will be same for both cases.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What your seeing is a compiler optimization. When `javac` encounters `method1()` it applies an optimization (based on De Morgan's Laws as you pointed out but also short circuiting the `&&`  comparison) that allows it to branch early if `a` is `true` (thus no need to evaluate `b`).

Comment: In `method1` though, couldn't it also branch early if `a` is true, because there would be no need to evaluate `b`?

Comment: @jlars62 It's easier for the compiler to distribute the `NOT` so that the first comparison can be represented as a single bytecode `ifne` (value is not zero/false), which if it succeeds branches to instruction 16 immediately skipping the other comparison.

Comment: @Dev OP didn't state that he is using `javac`. It can by any other Java compiler, for example ECJ (Eclipse Compiler for Java).

Comment: @jlars62 it can branch early if `a` is `true` and, in fact, it does so. `ifne` means “branch if true” and if a compiler implements the `a||b` using `ifne` both can jumps can target the same code representing the outer `not` which is implemented by just swapping the `iconst_1` and `iconst_0` instructions. And that’s what it is all about: the result is exactly the same code as for method2. The compiler does not need to transform one code to another; implementing the boolean expression just works that way, the same logic generates the same code.

Answer (score 18):

> Why is `method1` and `method2` the same at the Bytecode level?

You have very much answered this question yourself by pointing out the equivalence of the two methods if one applies De Morgan's transformation to it.

> But why does `method1` look like `method2` as opposed to `method2` looking like `method1`?

This assumption is not correct: it's not that `method1` looks like `method2` or `method2` looks like `method1`: rather, both methods look like some `methodX`, which looks like this:

```
public static boolean methodX() {
    if (a) {
        return false;
    }
    return !b;
}
```

Both methods are simplified to that logic due to short-circuiting. The optimizer then merges the two `ireturn` branches by inserting the `goto`s to different labels.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `if(a) return false;`? Without the `not`?

Comment: @Holger You are right, the `!` should be removed. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 7):

As you said, both methods express the same math. How a specific compiler produces bytecode is up to the compiler author, as long as it is correct.

It is not at all certain that the compiler applied DeMorgan's law. It seems to me that there may be simpler optimization techniques that would result in the same optimization.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that *It is not at all certain that the compiler applied DeMorgan's law*.

Answer (score 6):

Because your Java compiler is optimizing (using [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)) both methods to the same bytecode:

```
0: getstatic     #2 // static boolean a
3: ifne          16 // if a != 0 jump to 16 (return false)
6: getstatic     #3 // static boolean b
9: ifne          16 // if b != 0 jump to 16 (return false)
12: iconst_1        // push int value 1 on the top of the stack
13: goto         17
16: iconst_0        // push int value 0 on the top of the stack
17: ireturn         // return an int from the top of the stack
```

Answer (score 3):

Well in short the complier optimized it. To explain it futher: This is how `ifne` [opcode](http://www.vmth.ucdavis.edu/incoming/Jasmin/ref-ifne.html) is explained:

> ifne pops the top int off the operand stack. If the int does not equal
>   zero, execution branches to the address (pc + branchoffset), where pc
>   is the address of the ifne opcode in the bytecode and branchoffset is
>   a 16-bit signed integer parameter following the ifne opcode in the
>   bytecode. If the int on the stack equals zero, execution continues at
>   the next instruction.

So this is the sequence:

```
 load a
 if a == 0 (i.e. false) then load b 
    else then jump and return iconst_0 (false)
 if b is loaded and b == 0 then return iconst_1 (true)
    else return false
```